# How to center these icons inside the buttons?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm working on a markdown editor. I'm using **mdi font** for my icons.
I have a problem while trying to center the icons inside the toolbar buttons, for now it looks like that:

[image: an image of a button inside the toolbar]

This is the css rule that I use:

```css
.markdown-editor-button {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: transparent;
    color: #a2a2a2;
    font-family: "Material Design Icons";
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

So how to center the icons properly?

Comment: Set the right margin higher than the left

Comment: I will try that

Comment: Padding will probably work better actually

Comment: Wait, this is a text inside an element, not a text inside an element inside an element.

Comment: Padding and margin will not gonna work here

Comment: Yes, so give the icons you are having trouble with styles that apply an internal right-padding that is higher than the left padding, padding works on the inside of an element and margin works on the outside.

Comment: As you can see [here](https://codepen.io/Libruhh/pen/GRgYNdR), I am able to put the text wherever I want inside the div with padding.